# Is it safe to use tags to select a button in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

First of all, can you tell me why `btnSelected.id` does not return the actual id of the selected button?

Here I have implemented a function for 9 different buttons.

```
fun btnClick(view: View){

        val btnSelected = view as Button
        var cellID = 0

        when(btnSelected.id){
            R.id.btn1 -> cellID = 1
            R.id.btn2 -> cellID = 2
            R.id.btn3 -> cellID = 3
            R.id.btn4 -> cellID = 4
            R.id.btn5 -> cellID = 5
            R.id.btn6 -> cellID = 6
            R.id.btn7 -> cellID = 7
            R.id.btn8 -> cellID = 8
            R.id.btn9 -> cellID = 9
        }
        Log.d("btnClicked:",btnSelected.id.toString())
        Log.d("cellID:",cellID.toString())
    }
```

Instead, can I use Tags to select these buttons?

**activity_main.xml:** Adding tag attribute to all the 9 buttons.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:tag="1"
    android:background="@color/colorBox"
    android:onClick="btClick"
    android:layout_width="40pt"
    android:layout_height="40pt" />
```

code for button click:

```
fun btClick(view: View) {
    val btSelected = view as Button
    var cellId = btSelected.tag
}
```

Will this cause any problems in the future?

Comment: "can you tell me why btnSelected.id does not return the actual id of the selected button?" -- it does. What makes you think that it does not? "I have implemented a function for 9 different buttons" -- note that your code refers to values like `btn1`. Your XML refers to `bt1`. "Will this cause any problems in the future?" -- AFAIK, it should be OK. I rarely see people use `getTag()`/`setTag()` nowadays, but I am not aware of any particular problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare Whenever I clicked any button the `Log.d("btnClicked:",btnSelected.id.toString())` printed `D/btnClicked:: 2131165250` 
 `D/btnClicked:: 2131165251`  `D/btnClicked:: 2131165252`. I am new to android so I thought these values were the button id. What are they?

Comment: They are the button IDs. `R.id` values look like that, as they are code-generated numbers.